# Arduino (Gyroscope/Accelerometer) Visualizaion into Processing (3d cube)

Tags: processing, visualization, accelerometer, gyroscope

Im working on a device that uses an accelerometer and a gyroscope.
It works, but i want to go to the next level into precision, to do it i think the best path is go deep into real-time visualisation...

I watch some youtube videos and it seems that i can create a processing app to read the values from the sensor and visualise a moving "cube" (using accelerometer and gyroscope, some sort of IMU)

I want to learn to make a rotating AND moving cube... How can i learn to do this Arduino/processing application? Some useful wiki/documents will be very useful.

Comment: The arduino would only acquire data - the real work would be done on the host system, so this is not really an arduino question.  But also be aware that affordable inertial sensors have error which quickly accumulates to absurdity if you try to integrate them to find position or even velocity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, i understand what you are saying, you are right about it. Im removing the Arduino tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

- [FreeIMU](http://www.varesano.net/projects/hardware/FreeIMU) - You'll find a lot of tutorials and videos.
- [Bildr Tutorial](http://bildr.org/2012/03/stable-orientation-digital-imu-6dof-arduino/) - A very nice tutorial.

Hope this helps. :)